# Angular2 pass authorization inside header request

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am trying to authorize user by sending **btoa** encyption login string to **request headers** in angular2 but headers is sending **authorization** key inside **request payload**. 
Please refer to the screenshot

[image]

**Login Service:**

```
import { Http, Headers, Response, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';

let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append('Authorization', loginString);

return this.http.post('http://localhost:9090/api/users/authenticate', 
{headers: headers}).map(res => res.json());
```

I want to send **Authorization** key inside **Request Headers** instead of **Request Payload**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing your headers in the body parameter, try this

```
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';

let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append('Authorization', loginString);

const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

return this.http.post('http://localhost:9090/api/users/authenticate', 
null, options).map(res => res.json());
```

Comment: Thanks, It does work also i imported RequestOptions from '@angular/http'

Comment: great if it worked for you please mark the answer as accepted so others can find it easily if they get stuck. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `POST` request. The place where you put your header is actually where the body should be. However, what you are doing would be correct for a `GET` request.